# What is "libgnarl"?

Tags: ada, gnat

What is `libgnarl`? I find references to this in various places, like within the gcc source or in the verbose output from gprbuild. gprbuild specifically reports about deciding if `libgnarl` is even necessary, so it's clearly an optional library, but what's is the actual library? I can't find any documentation on it. The sources contain a bunch of packages that look like they'd belong in the standard library, but aren't (like `Ada.Execution_Time.Timers`), so clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can google for e.g. "ada gnarl" and find some fairly detailed info.

It’s the part of the RTS that handles tasking, so, broadly, if your program doesn’t use tasking it won’t need libgnarl.

Historically, it was developed as a joint project of the NYU GNAT team and Florida State University’s PART team: from an [FSU report in the ACM Digital Library](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/200000/197989/p97-giering.pdf?ip=62.64.199.27&id=197989&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2EACA724ACB6F70254%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1530279427_db55c572c522a0ac872bcb92b72bfba9),

> The development GNARL is a cooperative effort of the Florida State University POSIX/Ada Real-Time (PART) project with the NYU GNAT development team. The goal of the PART project is to advance the development and standardization of Ada language bindings to the IEEE POSIX standards, a family of application program interfaces for operating system services. A central concern of the PART project has been reconciliation of the Ada tasking model with the proposed standard POSIX thread services (Pthreads).

Embedded RTSs from AdaCore (at least the ARM ones) seem not to retain this distinction: in at least one, `libgnarl.a` contains only `empty.o`! However, AdaCore have continued the approach of incorporating academic RTS developments into their embedded RTSs, see `s-bb.ads` (`bb` => Bare Board):

```
--        Copyright (C) 1999-2002 Universidad Politecnica de Madrid         --
--             Copyright (C) 2003-2004 The European Space Agency            --
--                     Copyright (C) 2003-2018, AdaCore                     --
```

Comment: Oddly, searching exactly that yielded absolutely nothing about it for me in the top 5 pages, other than one entry of a bug report regarding libgnarl on HP-UX.
Thanks!

Comment: Clearly Google’s results depend very much on who’s asking them! (location? search history? eye colour?) Did you see [this one](http://www.iuma.ulpgc.es/users/jmiranda/gnat-rts/node14.htm)? (I’m not sure about the GNULL part, I think that’s taken over by `System.OS_Interface`.)

Comment: No I haven't seen that either. Thanks! I'm actually a medical worker, not a professional programmer, so if I search for "ada" I mostly get the law, even if I add "programming" or similar.