# build libada from gcc source

Tags: gcc, ada

I tried to build gnat compiler from gcc-11.2.0 with following script

```
./configure --prefix="/root/gcc-11" --enable-languages="c,c++,ada"  --enable-libada
```

then I get a gnat compiler but without ada standard library and found that the library's build script **libada.gpr** in **gcc-11.2/gcc/ada/libgnat/** can be standalone.

GPR tools tells that it needs **libgnarl.lst** to continue when tried to use `gprbuild -Plibada` to build libada.

Here's my questions:

1. what's the difference between libgnat & libgnarl
2. where can i get libgnarl.lst
3. are there guides for build libada?

Comment: See also [_What is "libgnarl"?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095571/what-is-libgnarl)

Answer (score 3):

`libgnarl` contains the tasking elements of the runtime, `libgnat` contains the rest. They’re split so that a program that doesn’t do tasking can be smaller than it would otherwise need to be.

The [GCC installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) contain, in the *Configuration* section,

> First, we **highly** recommend that GCC be built into a separate directory from the sources which does not reside within the source tree. This is how we generally build GCC; building where srcdir == objdir should still work, but doesn’t get extensive testing; building where objdir is a subdirectory of srcdir is unsupported.

My experience building GCC like that is that the runtime gets properly built. (This may not be the case for less common OSs; what’s yours?).

After such a build, I found these files lurking amongst many others in `$build/gcc/ada/rts/`:

```
libada.gpr
libgnarl.gpr
libgnarl.lst
libgnat.gpr
libgnat.lst
libgnat_common.gpr
```

and I get the *strong* impression (from `libada.gpr`, particularly) that these are intended to **re**build the runtime for a specific purpose.